# Сохранение в Joomla

Tags: joomla, denwer

Парни первый день на Joomla 1.6.5
Изменяю что нибудь через "Панель управления" ничего не меняется,в адресной строке просто добавляется "#".
Сайт стоит дома так сказать.Поставил его с помощью Денвера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была такая штука на j1.5. Вероятные причины:

1. Не догрузились файлы. Солюшн: переустановить.
2. Глючный мутулз. Солюшн - хз как правильно, я его переставлял руками, скачав с оф.сайта.

В любом случае откройте консоль ошибок и наслаждайтесь джумлой))